# Preventing BASH from evaluating filenames in variables

Tags: bash, variables

```
#!/bin/bash
#trash.sh

$TRASHDIR=$HOME/trash 
#Does not exist yet, i have loops further in 
#the script to check if the dir exists and to create it if not
echo $TRASHDIR
#I have ommited the rest of the script, 
#because this is where I have the problem
```

Let's run this:

```
./trash.sh  
./trash.sh: line 3: =/home/someuser/trash: No such file or directory
```

How can I store this filename in a variable without bash evaluating it? Also: How do I use this variable later for tests?

```
if [ -e $TRASHDIR ]
then
  echo stuff here
fi
```

Comment: You should also double-quote your variable interpolations.  Everywhere the variable occurs with a dollar sign, you want to put it inside double quotes.

Comment: There is no need to quote your variables in a test if you use `[[`, even if it contains embedded spaces: `if [[ -e $TRASHDIR ]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Leave the initial `$` character off when you *define* a var:

```
TRASHDIR=$HOME/trash
```

When you use `$TRASHDIR`, `bash` evaluates that as the empty string (or something else if was set previously), which is why it looks like:

```
=/home/someuser/trash
```